# How to validate mime type RFC 1521 sytnax in java?

Tags: java, validation, mime-types, rfc, media-type

Is there any standard framework to validate media type [RFC 1521](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1521.txt) syntax in Java?

So the type / subtype should be checked for syntax, allowing also application/vnd-.. standard extensions and any free application-specific definitions.

I would like to check definitions of REST API for usage in JAX-RS @Consumes / @Produces annotations. Target is to filter litter input, such as "123te{xt/pl..ain ; .---x" with characters not allowed in the media/mime type syntax at that position.

The parameter addition (after the semicolon) should be a parsing option, if possible.